# Rails 3 - Get User's LDAP membership including nested groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ldap, nested

I'm trying to get all the LDAP groups (including nesting) for a specific user based on his cn.
The goal would be to end up with a set of ul and li tags representing a tree of the groups nesting.
I can see how to do that nicely by calling a method recursively from my view, but i guess it would be better if my controller could return a single @ldap_user_membership object, or something like that, that contains the whole lot.

I have already got the ldap connection working and bound to our active directory and managed to get the membership for a user, but i'm just looking for the Rails way to do it.

Has anyone done that before ?

Comment: Have you been able to retrieve nested groups for a given user?